# Default txpower is 31dBm and is unable to connect in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager, macbook-pro

I have a 2017 Macbook Pro which I installed Ubuntu 20.04 on - everything has been working fine except the Wifi. Initially it just wouldn't connect, it would perpetually say "connecting" but never actually get an IP or connect to the network. Instead, after a bit of trying to connect it would re-ask for login credentials and repeat this process.

No drivers are needed, and I've tried all the solutions I could find pertaining to driver installations with no luck. After going through a lot of questions on here and other forums and trying everything, I finally found the only solution that works is to set my `wlp2s0` interface to have a txpower of 10dBm instead of the 31dBm used by default on boot. But somehow that fixes it right up.

This means whenever I turn on my computer I have to run:

```
# Sometimes wifi does not show up at all, so first we stop and start network-manager:
sudo service network-manager stop && sudo service network-manager start

# Then after the perpetually connecting issue we update wlp2s0 txpower:
sudo iwconfig wlp2s0 txpower 10dBm
```

before wifi will work. But running this on boot for me means making a script and other stuff I don't like as I can forget and could confuse me down the road. *BTW if anybody knows a better way to have txpower be persistently set for an interface that would also be helpful.*

But my main question is, why? I tried setting `/etc/default/crda` to be US as the regulatory domain, but no luck. Also 31dBm should be fine, no? If not then why would this be the default?

**Relevant Command Outputs (feel free to ask for more if helpful)**

iwconfig on startup:

```
wlp2s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=31 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
```

iwconfig after running my commands and connecting to my wifi:

```
wlp2s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"MY_WIFI_NETWORK_SSID"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.462 GHz  Access Point: ______________   
          Bit Rate=144.4 Mb/s   Tx-Power=10 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=30/70  Signal level=-80 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:42  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0
```

**NOTE: I tried other regulatory domains all of which did nothing. This made me think it was a technical limitation of my card, however both 20dBm and 15dBm also do not work. In either case, why would it default to an unusable 31dBm?**

Comment: I doubt you every find it out the reason for this problem, set it by script on boot and be done with it. Life is too short to waste it, with more time spent on this.

Comment: Yeah, I kind of figured :( But I feel like there may be someone much smarter than us on here that could potentially shed some light. Especially given how weird this is, I am going to leave it here for now and see if anybody knows :)